# Find matches in two very large lists in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two very large lists. One contains about 130,000 items (List A), the other contains around 600,000 columns (List B). I need to know which items in List A appear in List B, but I'm running into a constraint with processing time.

My normal approach would be something like this:

Put List A in column A and List B in column B. Put the following in C1:

```
=Not(IsError(Match(A1,B$1:B$600000,0)))
```

Then I would fill that down to C130000.

Obviously, this would work with two lists 100 items long. However, the lists are so large that this would take far too long for my computer to handle.

Is there a method that I can use in Excel that would work for lists this large without taking a month to process? Or do I need to start looking into other options?

Using Office 365

Comment: You need to look at an Access database.

Comment: if I were you, I prefer to use Python to handle this kind of request.

Answer (score 0):

The code below checked 100 items within 6.2 seconds. At that rate it should finish the job on 130,000 within 15 minutes. You might use the same test to see how much longer it would take to process longer strings.

```
Private Sub SearchForDuplicates()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Arr As Variant, Arr2 As Variant
    Dim R As Long, i As Long
    Dim Tstart As Single

    Tstart = Timer
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(600000, 1))
    Arr = Rng.Value
    ReDim Arr2(1 To 130000)
    Randomize
    For R = 1 To UBound(Arr2)
        Arr2(R) = Int((1200000 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
'        If R Mod 10000 = 0 Then Debug.Print R, Timer - Tstart
    Next R
    For R = 1 To UBound(Arr2)
        For i = 1 To UBound(Arr)
            If Arr2(R) = Arr(i, 1) Then
                Debug.Print "Found"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        If R Mod 100 = 0 Then Exit For
'        If R Mod 1000 = 0 Then Debug.Print R, Timer - Tstart
    Next R
'    Rng.Value = Arr
    Debug.Print Timer - Tstart
End Sub
```

Note that the time I measured includes time to set up the 730,000 strings for testing

Answer (score 0):

Sort the 600000 list in column B. Then in column C use

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$B$600000,1,True)=A1,"Match","")
```

And copy the formula down for the 130000 items in column A.

The calculation takes 0.04 seconds on my machine for just over 100000 items in column A (the speed of binary search is amazing)

Comment: Does this formula  require any restriction related to sorting of data or data in two list could be unsorted or many instances of an entry in a single list.

Comment: Column B needs to be sorted ascending. Column A does not need to be sorted. Since the formula is only looking for matches it does not matter if there are duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.